# Create a clickable timeline chart form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

At my work, I need to create a **timeline chart form** using **java script / jquery** that can give the possibility to do some actions or functionalities (adding new activities, …) and this must be done within the timeline chart ( clickable form with some pop-ups ).

I knew it is a little unclear description, I did try to simplify it with this:

[image]

I'm new in java script and jquery so I search some guidance ( some libraries, document, links, …) to help me out.
And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, After some research I find this JQuery Gantt-like chart with stacked activities/tasks:

[image]

At [github : https://github.com/demarchisd/stacked-gantt](https://github.com/demarchisd/stacked-gantt).

And it is really helpful ( it can be customized ).
and I hope it helps someone else like me.